# long time running python script

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi

I have application of following parts:

```
client->nginx->uwsgi(python)
```

and some python scripts can be running long time (2-6 minutes). After execution of script I should give to client content, but connection break with error "gateway timeout 504". What can I use for my case to avoid this error?

Comment: 6 minutes for request is very very slow, your clients dont be enjoy about your program. At the first to try setup caching system and optimize db (like denormalize and slicing if you have huge tables).

Comment: Can you divide the script execution into several parts?

Comment: No, I can't divide the script. And script don't makes query to DB and dont sends many content. It is just algorithm for image processing, but algorithm need some time (2-6 minuts) for to make result. And my clients understand and willing to wait.

Answer (score 2):

So is your goal to reduce the run time of the scripts, or to not have them time out? Browsers are going to give up on a 6 minute request no matter what you try.

Perhaps try doing the work on the server, and then polling for progress with AJAX requests?

Or, if possible, try optimizing the scripts.  For example, if you have some horribly slow SQL stuff going on, try cleaning that up.

Otherwise, without more information, a more specific answer is hard to give.

Comment: I'd like to avoid time out. I can't make valuable optimization because script makes processing a image and this algorithm can't work faster.

Comment: maybe I can change source code of nginx for increase time of connection between nginx and uwsgi (or nginx and client)?

Comment: AJAX would seem to be the only reasonable solution: have the processing continue in the background on the server while a “status: processing” page is immediately returned to the user, which contains periodic polling JavaScript code to retrieve the result once it’s available.

Answer (score 0):

I once set up a system where the "main page" contained an Iframe which showed the output of the long running program as text/plain.  I think the the handler for the the Iframe content was a Python CGI script which emitted all headers and then the program output line by line under an Apache server.

I don't know whether this would work under your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This heavily depends on your server setup (i.e. how easy it is to push data back to the client), but is it possible while running your lengthy application to periodically send some “null” content (e.g plain newlines assuming your output is html) so that the browser thinks this is just a slow connection and not a stalled one?